# 401 for PostRequest with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, scala, httpurlconnection

**UPDATE**
My problem turned out to be due to some super-class weirdness. However, the urlEncode in this example is wrong. In this case it was also unnecessary. If needed it should be done by each key and value without encoding & or =.
Other than that, this code is correct.

---

The (scala) code below fails because the server does not seem to receive the body.
The warning on the server log is:

> WARNING *** OAuthTokenProcessor caught a OAuthRequestProblemException with message OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='Missing grant_type parameter value', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}

I am certain that the params are correct. The url is correct, The headers are correct
(This call already works in Postman and Python)

Any hints deeply appreciated!

```scala
private def doPostRequest(): Unit ={
  try {

    val connectionforPost = (new URL(url)).openConnection.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]


    val params = "grant_type=password&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=seccret&username=admin&password=xxxx"
    val encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(params,"UTF-8")
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
    val postData = encodedString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

    val contentlength = Integer.toString(encodedString.length)

    connectionforPost.setConnectTimeout(50000)
    connectionforPost.setReadTimeout(50000)
    connectionforPost.setRequestMethod("POST")
    connectionforPost.setDoOutput(true)
    connectionforPost.setDoInput(true)
    connectionforPost.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
    connectionforPost.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "test bot")
    connectionforPost.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    connectionforPost.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*")
    connectionforPost.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive")
    connectionforPost.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", contentlength)
    connectionforPost.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    connectionforPost.setUseCaches(false)


    import java.io.DataOutputStream

    val wr = new DataOutputStream(connectionforPost.getOutputStream)
    wr.write(postData)
    if (wr != null) wr.close()



  } catch{
    case e:Exception => logger.error(e.getMessage,e)
      throw e
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `encodedString`?

Comment: grant_type%3Dpassword%26client_id%3Dxxxxx%26client_secret%3Dseccret%26username%3Dadmin%26password%3Dxxxx

Comment: You've encoded the '=' and '&' characters. While they need to be encoded if they appear in the values you are passing, they shouldn't be encoded in the body of the post

Comment: but then there is nothing to encode. When I try passing the string unencoded, I get the same error

Comment: Try to look at exactly what the difference between the working and not-working requests is. Use a tool to log the request at a low level.

Comment: There is an option to see the entire curl request in postman. It will help you find the differences.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the server complains that you are not logged in. You get an authentication problem exception. How it usually works is that you send a request to the server to login with the user name and password. If the server authenticates you (recognizes your user name and password as valid ones) it sends you a response with an authentication token in the headers. You may see those 2 headers in your response to successful login:

```
 access-control-expose-headers=[Authorization], Authorization=[Bearer ....]
```

This means that in all your subsequent requests you will need to add a header "Authorization" that will hold the value "Bearer ....". Then the server will recognize this request as coming from an authenticated user. 
Also, I suggest that you may use a 3d party HTTP client. Some well-known clients are [Appache HTTP client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/index.html) and [OK HTTP client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/). I use my own Http client that I wrote. It is also available as part of a MgntUtils Open Source Library. Here is the link to [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and it is also available on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) with source code and JavaDoc. And here is a javadoc page for [HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). Here is the code sample on how you may obtain the token and use it:

```
        try {
        HttpClient loginClient = new HttpClient();
        loginClient.setConnectionUrl("http://your_url/login");
        loginClient.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        loginClient.setContentType("application/json");
        String result = loginClient.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.POST, "{ \"username\": \"your_user_name\", \"password\": \"Your_password\"}");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("HTTP " + loginClient.getLastResponseCode() + " " + loginClient.getLastResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("Response headers: " + loginClient.getLastResponseHeaders());
        String accessControlExposeHeader = loginClient.getLastResponseHeader("access-control-expose-headers").get(0);
        String accessKey = loginClient.getLastResponseHeader(accessControlExposeHeader).get(0);
        HttpClient workingClient = new HttpClient();
        workingClient.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        workingClient.setContentType("application/json");
        workingClient.setRequestProperty(accessControlExposeHeader, accessKey);
        workingClient.setConnectionUrl("http://yourUrl/yourPath");
        System.out.println(workingClient.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.GET));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(TextUtils.getStacktrace(e));
    }
```

Comment: thanks!
As note in update, my core issue was due to some weird super-class processes unrelated to the code in the question.
Even so, this answer is totally on topic and very nicely explained